# How to get rid of adding :8000 to your local laravel url

Tags: apache, laravel, nginx, homestead

I am testing some sites locally. With every site I install, I usually follow the same format [site-name].[com/app/whatever] and when I view in my browser, I have to add :8000. If don't add that, I get directed to the Apache2 default page.

My question is what config files do I play with to eliminate having to add the port number, and just use the url that I typed in my yaml and hosts files? This is important because I am testing a site for someone that doesn't use the port format, and it is throwing off some of the sites redirects.

I don't want to edit each project file to add this, and im sure there's some nginx or apache file on my box that controls this.

**Edit** Even though I figured this out feel free to offer better explanations.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved it!** Thanks to this resource https://laravel-news.com/2014/09/removing-port-8000-homestead/.

Just add the IP from your Homestead.yaml file to your /etc/hosts file(instead of localhost IP), and you will not have to add :8000 to your local development.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try Laravel Homestead, it's a vagrant box with all the development environment you need for your project, you could check that out here.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/2

Comment: Love homestead. That is in fact what i am using :)

Comment: Then you just need to add the host to your hosts file `/etc/hosts` and point the homestead ip `192.168.10.10` to the url you want